# Unable to initialize device PRN in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I attempt to run a python program and the following pops up in command prompt:

"Unable to initialize device PRN"

I should also mention that the program runs fine.

Comment: take a look at the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/microsoft.public.office.misc/SOCmfso9Hkw)

Answer (score 72):

I had this same problem when I accidentally typed "**print** program.py" instead of "**python** program.py".  The error message comes from the Windows command-line program named `print`.  Those who suggested restarting the command prompt probably committed the same typo without noticing, and corrected it in their new command prompt.

Comment: I Imagine the majority of people have a python script and have accidentally tried executing it without feeding it to the python command and hence it's been treaded as a batch command and this error has occurred on meeting the first 'print' function/statement.

Comment: Damn it... made the same mistake ... even after 10+ years of writing Python ;)

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this in VS Code. I had run some lines of code (using Shift + Enter), which starts a Python interpreter in a terminal, and then I called `quit()` at the terminal, to exit Python. If you try to run some more lines of code, it doesn't start another Python interpreter, it just runs those lines in the terminal, which of course doesn't work and causes error messages like the one in the question.

Two easy solutions are either to start a new Python interpreter in the terminal (by entering `python`), or killing the active terminal instance (the dustbin icon), before running more lines of code.

Comment: The same problem as yours, ran few python lines using Shift+Enter, then exited the python interpreter using exit() and next time when I ran python lines using Shift+Enter, it gave the error message: " Unable to initialize device PRN". I used your solution and it worked perfectly. But I did not know how to kill terminal using "the dustbin icon", instead I typed "exit" in the terminal, and my problem is gone. Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I experienced this issue in VS Code after installing the latest version of Python and the Python extension.

To fix it, I just needed to add the Python installation path to my `PATH` environment variable.

> - On Windows 10, go to **Settings** and search for **Environment**
> - Click on **Edit environment variables for your account**
> - Select **Path** and click the **Edit** button
> - If the path to your **Python.exe** is not listed, click the **New** button
> - Enter the path to your **Python.exe** application and click the **OK** button
>
>   - The path for me was **`%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python37-32\`**
> - Restart VS Code and try to run your python script again

Answer (score 3):

First of all install latest version of Python from it's official website (i.e. python.org/download) after that if you try to run it through command prompt instead of writing **python3** just write **python**. After that **>>** it will appear then start writing your actual code. Make sure you re-run the command prompt window.[image: Sample Image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with python.  In the window above, the user has used the 'print' command on the command line, not within python.

Answer (score 2):

In my case restarting (close / open new) the console or the Command Prompt window works

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem by accidentally sending the word "print" to the command line from my programming which DOS interprets as the DOS command to print to the printer.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing name of the program; that worked for me.  Don't forget: use fresh cmd when you start executing.

Answer (score 1):

I am using VS code and I just noticed this issue today. Google a little and I comment out all the print function still not working. I exit the vs code and launch it again and it works just perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using Netstat print route in order to view the
routing table. It gave the error:
'Unable to initialize device PRN'
. It disappeared when I used the equivalent
netstat -r (and it did print out the routing table)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, add python.exe to system varible in your windows
On Windows 10, go to Settings and search for Environment
Click on Edit environment variables for your account
Select Path and click the Edit button
If the path to your Python.exe is not listed, click the New button
Enter the path to your Python.exe application and click the OK button
and restart the application

Answer (score 0):

Please try to enter python in terminal and then execute the same command .
In terminal type "Python" then run the command print("Hi"). It will work.