# I am just starting to learn python, and when I try to use print it tells me Unable to initialize device PRN

Tags: python-3.8

I use powershell, windows 10. I don't know why this wont work. Please tell how to fix this so I can use the print command.Unable to initialize device PRN, this is what it tells me when I try to use the print command.

Code I tried to run :
PS C:\Users\Nigel> print ('p')

Unable to initialize device PRN

PS C:\Users\Nigel>

Comment: Can you provide the source code you"re trying to run?

You might also want to check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983673/unable-to-initialize-device-prn-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first execute the `python` command before typing out python code on your cmd. Right now you are trying to type `print ('Hi')` on cmd directly which executes the windows cmd `print` command. Not executing python code. Once you execute `python` command you should see something like this in your cmd.

```
C:\Users\bswap>python
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

After which you can start executing python code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did that the first time I used Powershell then forgot every other time I went onto it.